# Why didn't the Avengers need this equipment?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* we see them use a

> Quantum tunnel for the time Heist

So how is it possible, that without this equipment Captain America and Iron Man can travel back to 1970 from the 2012 Battle of New York?

Even more so at the end when Captain America returns multiple stones just from a single quantum tunnel entry.

Comment: The quantum tunnel might be in charge of the entire trip - but it can be manually controlled by the 'time gps' units they carry.  A time machine by definition could potentially operate in more than one timeframe.  So yeah, the actual equipment is in one time and place - but who knows whether it can be controlled remotely.

Comment: Also .... wibbly wobbly timey wimey

Comment: Being careful with spoilers is really only needed for the title.

Comment: @iandotkelly I would tend to agree, but when I click on the avengers-endgame tag, it shows me a title and first two lines of text, which are full of spoilers.

Comment: Fair enough - I marked up the first 'spoiler' to fix this.  Though anyone who hasn't seen Endgame and is browsing a list of questions about the movie kind of deserves to be spoiled.

Comment: @Zikato Why do you click on the `avengers-endgame` tag to begin with?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson ... I don't think he's saying he did, but that when one does you get a list like that.

Comment: @iandotkelly I know. But then the question is why that hypothetical person clicked the tag if they don't want to see questions about it. What I'm trying to do is shift the spoiler discussion away from people hypothetically being possibly able to do things they are already well aware they just...shouldn't do.

Answer (score 2):

It seemed that it was always implied that they were brought back remotely through their compasses which connected them to the Quantum Tunnel, which would explain why they were using the compasses to get back.

The Gps' were a connection to the Quantum tunnel.

> Stark solves this with a "time-space GPS," a way for the team to
>   travel through the quantum bridge without getting lost in it. None of
>   any current science suggests that this is possible, writes Shankland.
>   But then he leaves the door open a tiiiiiiiny bit, giving us hope that
>   maybe that ugly brown van's quantum bridge was actually a wormhole
>   (!!!).
>
> With a form of so-called exotic matter -- something with negative
>   energy density -- you could prop wormholes open, but nobody knows if
>   this is even possible, except at the minutest quantum-mechanical
>   scales.
>
> What I'm hearing is that Hank Pym (the original Ant-Man, played by
>   Michael Douglas) and co. created a wormhole, accidentally left Scott
>   in it, and then the Avengers used the same wormhole and their GPS
>   devices to save this single universe.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Avengers: Endgame and time travel: Why it all makes perfect sense - CNET](https://www.cnet.com/news/avengers-endgame-time-travel-why-it-all-makes-perfect-sense/)</sub>

So, the GPS' give them access to the Quantum bridge with which they can travel further back in time (to get more Pym Particles) or back to the present.

Comment: That would get them back to the present. How did they jump again? They had only one shot remember. No more pym particles.

Comment: @bobbyalex Jumped to the military facility to steal more pym particles.

Comment: Surely that is not possible. If they can jump to anywhere on a whim then what was the fuss all about. If they botched the first try, they can do it again.. and again.

Comment: @bobbyalex Each one had two trips worth of Pym particles. One used on the way there, one used on the way back. Instead of using theirs to go back, Captain America and Iron Man use their "trip back" particles to go to 1970 where Hank Pym has recently invented the Pym particle - they steal another trips worth of particles and then travel back. They can't "do it again and again" because the original location doesn't have a supply of Pym particles they can easily steal...

Comment: Once the events of the final battle have transpired, they have an endless supply of Pym particles, because they can create more.